# Find eclipse setting name to set it in plugin_customization.ini

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add some default values for an eclipse plugin delivered as a whole eclipse product through `plugin_customization.ini`.

If I want by default to have the `Build automatically` disabled, I write in `plugin_customization.ini` the folowing line:
`org.eclipse.core.resources/description.autobuilding=false`

How can I find the `org.eclipse..../.../` setting name for disabling the spell checking for example? What about any other setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The settings are stored in `.pref` files in the workspace subdirectory `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`:

1. Before starting your application make a **copy of the `.settings`** folder
2. Start your application, **change the setting** and then exit the application
3. **Compare** the current `.settings` folder with the copied from step 1

In your case, disabling spelling will add the line `spellingEnabled=false` to `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`, so the line for `plugin_customization.ini` you are looking for is **`org.eclipse.ui.editors/spellingEnabled=false`**.

Comment: Thank you howgler!