# Disable eclipse default preference through pluginCustomization.ini file

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I want to disable the Java Development under Windows->Preferences->General->Capabilities using pluginCustomization.ini file.

I tried using
`org.eclipse.javaDevelopment=false`
but this didnt seem to work.

what is id that should be mentioned in pluginCustomization file so as to disable the Java Development?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021524/6505250

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. @howlger