# Disable missing project natures in Eclipse via code

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I have an itegration test that downloads and starts an Eclipse IDE and imports a Project to it. After importing the IDE suggests a `Groovy Project Nature` and opens the marketplace.

[image: marketplace groovy nature]

Through this behavior my test-case is failing and I don't want to test the project nature support in this scenario.

I am trying to disable the automatically detected project natures in Eclipse IDE before starting it. I know it can be disabled in the IDE under `Preferences -> Project natures`. But my test is downloading a fresh copy of Eclipse and then the settings are default.

So I need to find the flag in the IDE/workspace settings, because I want to disable it via code before the IDE is started.

So my question is: Where is the flag for missing project natures located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovering missing project natures and proposing corresponding Eclipse Marketplace entries can be disabled in ***Window > Preferences: General > Project Natures*** or via the following line in the [`plugin_customization.ini`](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_configproduct.htm) file:

```
org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui/org.eclipse.epp.mpc.naturelookup=false
```

See also [how to find a setting name to set it in `plugin_customization.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021524/6505250).

Comment: I see. The setting is stored in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.prefs` and can therefore also be disabled via `plugin_customization.ini` (see my edited answer).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you