# Restrict eclipse to open only one file from Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

How can I restrict eclipse to open only one file from Project Explorer. Can this be done with change in source of eclipse or is there any setting to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Editors_ you can check _Close editors automatically_ and enter `1` for the number of opened editors. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. Thank You :)

Comment: Can you please also tell if I want to make this a default setting in my custom eclipse then when in source should I make changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Editors*** check ***Close editors automatically*** and enter **`1`** for the number of opened editors.

Plese note, dirty editors will not be closed automatically: if an editor contains unsaved changes, another tab will be opened.

For a customized Eclipse, this setting can be set in the file `plugin_customization.ini` as follows (see [how to find these settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021524/6505250)):

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench/REUSE_OPEN_EDITORS_BOOLEAN=true
org.eclipse.ui.workbench/REUSE_OPEN_EDITORS=1
```