# Sonarlint Eclipse - List of Deactivated Rules

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm working with Sonarlint in Eclipse.  I see how I can activate/deactivate rules.  How can I obtain a list of all the rules that I deactivated in Eclipse?  I don't see where the Sonarlint plugin is storing them.  Note, I can't copy anything from the image shown below, but Sonarlint is pulling this list from somewhere.

[image: Sonarlint Rule Config]

Comment: You might be connected to a sonar cube or server which governs what rules are activated and disabled, if that is the case, managing it via the eclipse plugin will not yield much success. The idea of putting on them on the server is to enforce consistency.

Comment: If not connected to a server, have you already looked in [`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021524/6505250)?