# Restrict open Tabs in Eclipse RCP project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I was looking for an option to set the number of open tabs in a RCP application. Currently, I could do it by going to preference->editor settings and tick property of close editor on reaching a certain count. But I was looking for setting this property and count (like 10 active tabs) via .ini/.xml file or product file of the application. Any suggestions to this would be really helpful.

Comment: This can be done in the `plugin_customization.ini`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021524/6505250

Comment: @howlger Thanks a lot , this was a really helpful tip :)

Comment: Great. Should I close the question as a duplicate (even if it is not a 100% duplicate) or do you want to answer it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this customization goto  `plugin_customization.ini` of the application plugin
and add the following lines:

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench/REUSE_OPEN_EDITORS=10
org.eclipse.ui.workbench/REUSE_OPEN_EDITORS_BOOLEAN=true
```

where the number of open editors can be configured as required.
Save the file and re-run the application.